# Generic collection <K,V> with ability sorting and get by position

Tags: java, android, generics, dictionary

I know that **ArrayList** provide ability to get item at position `get(position)`, and **LinkedHashTable** provide sorting, but it not able to get item at position. So,  question: is any generic collection in java with features:

- sorting
- get by position
- provide Key/Value generic type.

Please, give me code example of listed features, if required generic exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I apologize for over complicating things earlier!

Use a TreeMap. When you want to

```
get(position)
```

just do the following:

```
K key = treemap.getKeys().get(position)
V value = treemap.get(key);
```

==========================

My old over complex incorrect answer from before:

You can use an `ArrayList<Pair<K implements Comparable,V>>` where you implement comparable on the `Pair<K,V>` and K has Comparable implemented. Then you can use `Collections.sort(List<Pair<K,V>)` on the Arraylist.

Then you would maintain a `HashMap<K,V>` so that you can retrieve elements by K. That means you will have to remember to update both data structures. That means O(N) to add an element :( . Also, to simplify the logic, you would wrap the HashMap and ArrayList in an object.

```
public class Pair<K extends  Comparable<K>, V> implements Comparable {

    private final K first;

    private final V second;

    public Pair(K first, V second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public K getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public V getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    public int compareTo(K other) ; // TODO
}
```

Comment: Can you provide any code sample which explain how to accomplish that?

Comment: Thanks, but in that case i not be able to get item `Pair<Integer,String>` by key, is any way to get item by key too?

Comment: No, in that case, I recommend maintaining a HashMap<> and an ArrayList<>. With that you'll be able to index by position, and retrieve values by a key.

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) or [SortedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) ??

Both TreeMap and SortedMap provides:

1. Provides Natural Sorting of Key Element.
2. Is a key/value pair
3. Gets a value based on a Key.

BTW:

**LinkedHashMap** just maintains an Insertion Order, it isn't Sorted, It is just has an Order

Comment: SortedMap get(key) - get by key but not by position, TreeMap - same i not found method like ArrayList.get(pos) - which provide get by position functionality.

Comment: @testCoder java.Util.Map implementing classes can only get elements based on key/value. LinkedHashMap maintains an Insertion order, it doesnt have indexes.

Comment: Does it mean that there is no way to get item by position?

Comment: @testCoderumm, none that i know of from standard java API